# php include not dispalying

Tags: php, include

I am making a website where the header and the footer will be the same for all pages. I have looked at a few tutorials on how to have a header.php and footer.php and then just call them where needed in each page.

However, I am having trouble implementing this.

In my index.php I use:

```
<?php include "header.php"; ?>
```

And my header.php looks exactly as follows (no code omited):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/layout.css" type="text/css" />
<!-- Homepage Specific Elements -->

<div class="wrapper row1">
 <div id="header" class="clear">
   <div class="fl_left">
     <h1><a href="index.html">hansmoolman.com</a></h1>
      <p>Art & Science</p>
   </div>
  <div class="fl_right">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">A - Z Index</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">Registration</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form action="#" method="post" id="sitesearch">
        <fieldset>
          <strong>Search:</strong>
          <input type="text" value="Search Our Website&hellip;" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='Search the Website&hellip;')? '' : this.value ;" />
          <input type="image" src="images/search.gif" id="search" alt="Search" />
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I run it, no header is displayed however. Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong with this?

Comment: Do you see the code when you view the source in your browser?

Comment: Are the files in the same folder, and did you turn on error reporting to see what the problem was.

Comment: Is there anything before/after the code in `index.php`?

Comment: Have you tried using `require` instead of `include`?

Comment: Add the line `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before your include.

Comment: try this: `<?php if(!require("header.php")){ echo "cannot find file to include" }; ?>`

Comment: Dont see the source code when viewing in browser and all the files are in the same folder. How do I turn on error reporting. Also just tried require but still no luck - still dont see header.

Comment: Tried <?php if(!require("header.php")){ echo "cannot find file to include" }; ?> but the page displays without error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found my error...Turns out it was between the seat and screen. Saved index as .html instead of .php.

Thanks for all the help from all.

Answer (score 0):

First, your header does lead to invalid HTML, because you're mixing head and body elements.

Despite of that:

1. Ensure to display HTML within the `body` element.
2. Ensure that the included file is where it is expected. You can test that by temporarily exchenge `include` with `require`. Program execution will then stop, if the file is not found.

Comment: Placed HTML in body tags and still no luck. Also swapped include for require as suggested "Program execution will then stop, if the file is not found", but the page displays (without the header).

Comment: Set your error_reporting to `E_ALL`, be sure to have `display_errors` enabled. If that does not help, please provide the (relevant part of the) code where you do the include.